# Tracing global variables use in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am new at LLVM and trying to write a custom analysis pass. Below is a llvm-ir snippet from my module.

```
1 @my_string = common global i8* null, align 8
2 %tmp1 = load i8*, i8** @my_string, align 8
3 call void @copy_string(i8* %tmp1, i8* %tmp2, i8* %tmp3)
```

I wish to make check, if one of the function parameters passed is a global variable or not? For instance in above example code, I wish to check if `%tmp1` is a global variable or not?

Could you suggest the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are directly using global pointer then you can check by isa<GlobalVariable> but if the variable is loaded as in you example, you can write a recursive function to get original pointer and then check if original pointer is to the global memory or not.  recursive function needs to handle the instruction types as load,store,getElementPtr, phi, select inst etc. (as per your use) and then get the pointer operand of that instrution as for load inst you can use psLoadInst->getPointerOperand() and again call the recursive function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply....
That is exactly what I did. I used InstVisitor to traverse recursively through the aliases back to the original load instruction. Then I checked if its pointer operand is a global pointer or not.